# How to send unchecked checkbox value that is not 0/false or 1/true but integers form 1 to 32

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, smarty

I have an array of checkboxes with some additional columns. When one is checked it its value is added on a MySQL table. Values from 1 to 32.

When one of them is unchecked I need to send MySQL the same data and with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE just to update the rest of the columns if changed.

I don't want to send 0 or 1 but the value from 1 to 32 in this case.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="add_value[]" id="add-value" value="{$values.id_value}"/><p>{$values.name} </p>
```

Comment: If a checkbox is checked, when the form is posted the `value` attribute determines what's posted to the server. If it's not checked, then *nothing* is posted. What is it that you want to work differently?

Comment: Yes, but then the MySQL is not updated. Or how can I force it to update?

Comment: Then make a SQL query to update it if your checkbox is not set. Use ISSET to check. If they don't check the box it won't be set, you can use a ternary operator to post your value

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment to what he's asking, you can do something like this:

```
$checkBoxValue = (ISSET($_POST['name']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Then just use a standard sql query to do what you need with it.

If you need a specific value for the checkbox you can use hiddens in conjunction to hold the value for you too.

Or even one more option you can do something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" id="status_1" name="status_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="status_2" name="status_2" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="status_3" name="status_3" value="1" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>    
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i<=count($_POST); $i++) {
        $_POST["status_$i"] = isset($_POST["status_$i"]) ? $_POST["status_$i"] : 0;
    }
    var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: The other option is you can create hidden if you need them to contain a specific value, and if it's not checked and the hidden exist's then you have your value.

Comment: I don't need to add 0 or 1 to the db but integers from 0 to 32. Check checked and submitted they are added tot he db, but when unchecked they are not. I just need to submit them so the db can be updated with some other info dependent on this column.

Comment: If that's all you need to do then you have all the information you need here to do that. Get creative with what i've provided you.

Comment: Thanks Tim, will experiment and report back!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1bit" />
<input type="checkbox" name="2bit" />
<input type="checkbox" name="4bit" />
<input type="checkbox" name="8bit" />
<input type="checkbox" name="16bit" />
```

Then in your receiver, something like

```
<?php
$num = 0;
if ($_REQUEST["2bit"]===1) $num += 1;
if ($_REQUEST["4bit"]===1) $num += 2;
...

?>
```

Then you can submit $num to your database. You also should add checks to make sure your field names (1bit, 2bit, etc) exist in the $_REQUEST array

Comment: Hum interesting, will test it out and report back it it worked.